# Preventing divs from clearing inside an animated container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a horizontal jQuery animated slider which works great, except as its width begins to decrease, no matter how I set up the `<divs>` inside they go to newline. I want them to stay on the same line to create this smooth illustion.

Here's what I mean: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9t61frxz/)

How do I prevent them from clearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `max-width` instead of `width`:

```
 #container { max-width:500px; height:500px;border:2px dotted maroon; }
    .red, .blue, .green { display:inline-block;max-width: 250px; height:50px; margin:0 auto;}
```

here is the jsfiddle [link](https://fiddle.jshell.net/vnqL3Ld6/)

**UPDATE**:
to avoid clear try [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m7mdr557/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I must not have been clear. I want them to act as if `clear:both`

Comment: In your example as soon as there's no room they "collapse" under each other if that's the right terminolog

Comment: that's EXACTLY what I wanted.

Comment: can you explain how that works? i still havea  few floats that are misbehaving

Comment: thats bcz max-width is set to 50% of the parent container.whatever be the its width the inner elements they will resize to  half of its width(parent container)